# How to make basic api call between two .net core apps that both use Windows Auth

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, windows-authentication

Trying to understand how to get authentication to work between two Visual Studio 2022 projects, both in .Net 6, for an intranet project.
I'm starting with baby steps, with the default code for these two projects:
Created a Blazor Server App project called *TestFront*: authentication type = Windows, checkbox for Configure for HTTPS left on.
Created ASP.NET Core Web API project called *TestApi*: authentication type = Windows, checkbox for Configure for HTTPS left on.

Running the *TestApi* project in IIS Express brings up the browser showing the WeatherForecast json - all good.

I then added another controller to *TestApi* called **Trial**:

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TrialController : ControllerBase
{
    public SecurityController()
    {
    }
    
    [HttpGet("TrialGet")]
    public int TrialGet()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

In project *TestFront*, added a button to the Index.razor component having a click event that makes this call:

```
...
int i = await new HttpClient().GetFromJsonAsync<int>("https://localhost:44334/Trial/TrialGet");
...
```

Started TestApi and TestFront, both in IIS Express. Clicked the button in TestFront, and caught the following error in my exception handler when executing the HttpClient line:
[image]

Have not been able to figure out why this Unauthorized 401 error is occurring. Both projects are setup to use Windows auth. What other 'plumbing' must be done to allow for a successful Api call? The posts I've found on SO for almost similar problems were for more complex scenarios, and the solutions I've tried to implement have not been successful for me.

Comment: Looks like this is the MS documenation on windows authentication: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @topsail - Thanks for the reply. My IIS Express and launchSettings.json settings already match with the documentation in the link you provided.